# Open source Matlab packaging tools

Tags: matlab, package

I've developed a Matlab toolbox of my own and what to share it with a community of Matlab developers. Are there any open-source Matlab package management tools (like conda or pip for Python) that I could use?

Comment: For sharing it, put it in the MATLAB FileExchange, better if you do it via a Github repo. With no offense of answers, those tools are not used by the community (such as pip or conda).

Answer (score 3):

There is a freely-available [tbxmanager](http://www.tbxmanager.com) supported by a single person but the list of packages in the related repository is short. The package manager is built for [MPT3](https://www.mpt3.org) (Multi-parametric toolbox).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a project for a pip-style access to the Matlab file exchange:

https://github.com/mobeets/mpm